# What are my most-liked Facebook posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Is there a way to rank all my Facebook posts (status updates, photos, links, etc.) by number of likes? How about a way to rank my friends by average number of likes on each friend's posts?

I found mention of [TopStats](http://www.facebook.com/topstats), which looked promising, but appears not to work anymore (redirects to the Facebook home page).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Login to [Archivedbook](http://archivedbook.com/) using Facebook. Select tab `Statuses` and from the drop down menu select `Most Liked`.
[image]

Comment: _"Unfortunately, Archivedbook will definitely stop working on April 30, 2015. [Read here why](http://archivedbook.com/this-is-the-end)."_

Answer (score 3):

As all of those apps no longer work here is my new Facebook app: "[Facebook Analytics](https://www.facebook.com/games/analytics-scholatec/)"

It will give you all those answers and more in a very user friendly way. It also works for pages. Here is the description from the page:

> A free tool for analysing your Facebook data. Use Analytics to know:
>
> - The total number of likes, comments and shares
> - Who comments and likes the most
> - Which users get the most likes and comments
> - Who the most influential users are
> - Which content generates the most interest
> - Who are the most influential users outside of your social circle

[image: Top Likers and Top Commenters]

[image: Top posts]

Comment: nothing works...

Comment: Can you please elaborate? We have no other reports of errors or bugs. I suggest report your bug here: https://www.facebook.com/analyticsbyscholatec/

Comment: Flash no longer supported. Is the message I get,

Answer (score 2):

Login to Wolframalpha.com

generate a detailed report about your social network, including the particular query you are interested in and all the other useful data.

great insights about your activity on the social network.

http://www.wolframalpha.com/facebook/

Answer (score 0):

http://truefbfriends.com will give you your most liked facebook pics. It is photos specific and not posts specific

Answer (score -1):

None of the above work, including the "Facebook Analytics," which, for me, at least, works ONLY with my pages, but, I didn't care about that, so I didn't run it. My guess is that Facebook decided not to allow third-party apps to gain so much access to users' data for, hopefully, obvious reasons. You'd think they'd have realized that a lot of people want to know which of their posts got the most "likes" (positive or negative), and come up with a way to do it, themselves via the "Activity Log."