# Find most liked photo on my Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, analytics

I am runnig a Facebook page for my own photos, sharing them with friends.
There is over 1000 photos this year, in about 10 albums.

Is there a way to statistically analyse individual photos? For example, the photo with most likes etc.

I found this question, but it is for whole posts, not individual photos:
[What are my most-liked Facebook posts?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26154/what-are-my-most-liked-facebook-posts)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are my most-liked Facebook posts?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26154/what-are-my-most-liked-facebook-posts)

Comment: See above. This method finds most liked posts, but i am looking for most liked individual photos inside posted albums.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, only [Facebook Analytics](https://analytics.facebook.com/) provides such kind of functionalities.
All other tools that you may find online are either not working,
or are illegal.
See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/86212/235148) that you might find helpful.