# How do I see my most liked posts on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I would like to know if there is a way to see which of my personal facebook posts (photos, text, links, etc. shared by me) obtained the most likes.

Ideally, I'd like to do it from within the facebook platform. Or, at least, without giving access to my personal data to dodgy third parties.

PS there is an old [post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26154/what-are-my-most-liked-facebook-posts) here asking for the same thing, but none of the softwares they indicate are still working